# How do I get rid of the default styling on a table object in a python-docx generated word document?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

Per the python-docx documentation the following code generates a simple table with three columns:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'
for item in recordset:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(item.qty)
    row_cells[1].text = str(item.id)
    row_cells[2].text = item.desc
```

However, the default styling of the row_cells[0] is bold. How do I get rid of the special styling on the first column?

(Also, if I could get rid of the default banded rows that would be great as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best bet for this sort of thing in the current version is to apply a table style, for example:

```
table.style = 'LightShading-Accent1'
```

It's possible to modify the table styles in Word in the ways you describe, e.g. header font, row banding, etc. So you can modify one of the existing styles to suit or create your own.

Make sure you study these two pages in the python-docx documentation to understand how to make styles available in your document at run time:

http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/styles.html
http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/documents.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to know styles in your document

```
styles = document.styles
for s in styles:
  print(s.name)
```

then
try this

```
table2 = document.add_table( rows=15, cols=15,style='Table Grid')
```

you can change style to whatever your document supports with

```
(style='Table Grid')
```

python 3.4 docx 0.8.6