# formatting a run within a loop and inserting in a table Python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to format text using python docx.  The text is a string pulled out by a loop.  How can I name the object a run and then apply a font to the run?

This is my code:

```
xcount = 0
while xcount < xnum:
    xdata = datastring[xcount]
    obj1 = xdata[0]
    run = obj1
    font = run.font
    from docx.shared import Pt
    font.name = 'Times New Roman'
    row1.cells[0].add_paragraph(obj1)
    xcount += 1
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'font'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdata[0]` is a string (doesn't have a `.font` attribute). You'll need to create a `Document()`, add a paragraph, and add a run to that. E.g.:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True
```

(copied directly from the docs: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 3):

Create Table :

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)


#Adding table 
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'
for item in recordset:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(item.qty)
    row_cells[1].text = str(item.id)
    row_cells[2].text = item.desc

document.add_page_break()
```

Read : [python-docx](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Then to style these tables :

```
#Table styling :
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        for paragraph in cell.paragraph:
            paragraph.style = 'CellText' # assuming style named "Cell Text"
```

Read : [apply a paragraph style to each of the paragraphs in each table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27852501/2142994)